# looking for constructive feedback on abstract algebra question

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, projection

Looking for constructive feedback on this. I don't know much abstract algebra so please take that into account when you give feedback.

Suppose one wants to map two class structures sitting in $\Bbb R^3,$ from  $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2,$ via projection.

Here $f$ represents a transformation (in this case a projection) that acts on the class structures $\Phi$ and $M.$ $S$ acts to generate the class structures respectively.

$f:\operatorname{class}\{\Phi_S(X)\} \to \operatorname{class}\{\Phi_S(X)\},$ via $f:= \Bbb P_\Phi:\Bbb R_\Phi^3\to \Bbb R_\Phi^2.$

$f^*:\operatorname{class}\{M_S(X)\}\to \operatorname{class}\{M_S(X)\},$ via $f^*:= \Bbb P_M: \Bbb R_M^3\to \Bbb R_M^2. $

That notation just describes the class structures being projected from $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2.$

Intersecting either class structure with a plane yields a ring structure. **I'm interested in describing such a ring structure after the projection.** Is using a graph a useful way? The reason I'm thinking that, is because the following graph encodes information about the ring structures, via intersections in a lower dimension than three.

Note: The graph includes four class structures mapped down to $\Bbb R^2,$ not just two. I denote the class structures as $\operatorname{class}\{\Phi_S(X)\}=(E,G)$ and $\operatorname{class}\{M_S(X)\}=(H,F).$ Here, the cardinality, or order of $S$ is: $|S|=11,$ because each class structure has $11$ outgoing/incoming edges.

[image]

The following is a specific representation of the four class structures sitting in $\Bbb R^3,$ before being mapped down to $\Bbb R^2.$

[image]

Comment: `Is using a graph a useful way?` I think normally the situation is that the burden is on the inventor of the way to tell others if it useful, not the other way around.

Comment: If you have some ring structure in $\mathbb R^3$, and some ring structure on $R^2$, then certainly their intersection is a ring, though.  What ring structures did you have in mind?

Comment: A constructive feedback? Why do you want a ring structure? Groups and graphs seem more natural to me here.

Comment: @rschwieb I had in mind a Noetherian ring.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about? I find this a bit difficult to follow. (What is a "class structure"?)